# JavaScript (for/while)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

In result I should get a spiral matrix but it's not working.The problem is somewhere in the 3rd or 4th `for` from `while`

The `for` loop is just not working. I think, logically, the problem is solved and I have just a syntax problem but I can't find it.

For example the matrix should look like this: 

`n=3            n=5

1  2  3        1  2  3  4  5
8  9  4        16 17 18 19 6
7  6  5        15 24 25 20 7
               14 23 22 21 8
               13 12 11 10 9`

```js
n = parseInt(prompt('N:', '5'));
A = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  A[i] = new Array();
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++) A[i][j] = 0;
}
DIM = parseInt(n * n);
//A[i][j]=1; 
//==========================
document.write("<br>Matrix: <table border='2'>".fontcolor('red'));
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  document.write("<tr>");
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    document.write("<td >" + A[i][j] + " ");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
document.write("</table>");
document.write("========================================== <br>");

//===========================
k = 1;
nr = 1;
f = true;
while (f) {
  i = k - 1;
  for (j = k - 1; j <= n - k; j++) {
    if (nr <= DIM) {
      A[i][j] = nr;
      nr++;
      document.write(A[i][j] + ' ');
    } else {
      f = false;
    };
  };
  document.write('<br>');
  for (i = k; i <= n - k; i++) {
    if (nr <= DIM) {
      A[i][j] = nr;
      nr++;
      document.write(A[i][j] + ' ');
    } else {
      f = false;
    };
  };
  document.write('<br>');
  for (j = (n - k - 1); j >= (k - 1); j--) {
    if (nr <= DIM) {
      A[i][j] = nr;
      nr++;
      document.write(A[i][j] + ' ');
    } else {
      f = false;
    };
  };
  document.write('<br>');
  for (i = (n - k - 1); i >= k; i--) {
    if (nr <= DIM) {
      A[i][j] = nr;
      nr++;
      document.write(A[i][j] + ' ');
    } else {
      f = false;
    };
  };
  document.write('<br>');
  k++;
};
//=====================================
document.write("<br>Matrix: <table border='2'>".fontcolor('red'));
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  document.write("<tr>");
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    document.write("<td >" + A[i][j] + " ");
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
document.write("</table>");
document.write("========================================== <br>");
```

Comment: `I have just a syntax problem` what does the console tell you, where does it indicate the syntax problem is? I would advise you give your variables some meaningful names, rather than `a`, `n`, `k`, `nr`, `f`. this will make it easier to read through the code to see what is suppose to be doing what. Also just as some other notes, I see no initial declaration of your variables (i.e. var n = ... ) and I see no `<table>` element being written yet you write rows, cells and a closing `</table>`

Comment: @Quince `document.write("<br>Matrix: <table border='2'>` is where the `<table>` starts.

Comment: @melpomene oh yeah, missed that, ok scratch that comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a syntax error. It's crashing on `A[i][j] = nr;` in the `for (j = (n - k - 1); j >= (k - 1); j--) {` for loop when you try to set `A[5][3] = 10;` because `A[5]` is undefined.

That should solve you immediate problem though I doubt that helps much... This is a legitimately tricky programming problem. A spiral seems so simple but it's actually quite hard. I'd highly recommend you take Quince's advice and improve your variable names. Trying to get this code to work would give anyone a headache.